# How to redirect to a new domain in Jboss Web

Tags: mod-rewrite, jboss

I have a web app running on Jboss Web and I'm trying to move a customer to another server. The system uses a query string with an entry like a=bmpj to identy the connecting customer. Basically I want to use this query string as a condition for redirecting to the new server. This is what I have below and I've tried various other combinations without success. What am I doing wrong? I've put other RewriteRules here and they have worked. To make sure they aren't interfering with each other I removed everything else but these two lines and still, nothing happens. Help please.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=bmpj.*
RewriteRule s01.myserver.com/app/?a=bmpj s02.myserver.com/app/?a=bmpj [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. This did it.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=bmpj.*
RewriteRule (.*) https://s02.myserver.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I'm still perplexed as to why my original attempt did not work. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.